# Is it a good practice to store session in two different places?

Tags: security, spring, session, redis, saml

I have a use case like this and I am wondering if this solution is a good practice or not.

Say I have a website called `dashboard.com` and this is only for `US region`. When users login here, I am storing their session into `USRedis` instance. However this dashboard has two buttons named `USWebApp` and `EUWebApp`.

Assume that this is the UI for `dashboard.com` (pardon for text based UI). The doted elements indicate html buttons. So I have two buttons named `USWebApp` and `EUWebApp`

```
http://www.dashboard.com

----------    ----------
|USWebApp|    |EUWebApp|
----------    ----------
```

Once user is logged into `dashboard.com` and clicks `USWebApp`, I pass the session cookie to `USWebApp` and `USWebApp` calls `USRedis` to validate the session. If session is not valid, then we redirect the user back to `dashboard.com` (and user logs in again by typing credentials).

On the contrary, user can click `EUWebApp`. Again I am passing `dashboard.com`'s session cookie to `EUWebApp`. However `EUWebApp` checks `EURedis` to validate this session. However when user logged into `dashboard.com` I only persisted their session to `USRedis`. So when `EUWebApp` tries to validate this session by looking in `EURedis`, it won't find the session since I never wrote to `EURedis` when user logged into `dashboard.com` (main site) in the first place to begin with.

Two solutions that I can think to solve this

1) `EUWebApp` should talk to **only** `USRedis`, to validate the session instead of talking to `EURedis` or

2) when user logs into `dashboard.com` I should store their session in both `USRedis` and `EURedis`. Therefore `USWebApp` can use `USRedis` while `EUWebApp` can use `EURedis` to validate the user session.

What do you guys think about this? Especially the 2nd approach? Is that a good practice?

Apart from these two approaches, do you know any other solutions for my architecture?

**More information in case interested:** (not really needed for this question)
I am building a main site and integrating with a SAML IDP(Identity provider). Think of dashboard.com as your company's main page where you have access to multiple apps like word, splunk, teams, etc.

Comment: Why dont you use a role based access system. For example us users are member of "usUsers" and EU users are member of "euUsers" and then you handle access in your based on role membership.

Comment: yes thats what I am doing. The idp sends those `usUsers` and `euUsers` roles in the saml response and based on that I either disable `USWebApp` or `EUWebApp` buttons. However if they have access to both, then we need both apps and hence the question, should I need to write to 2 redis instances so when user clicks `USWebApp`, the `USWebApp` can validate with `USRedis` and when user clicks `EUWebApp`, `EUWebApp` can validate their session with `EURedis`.

Comment: Then i cant understand why you need a usWebApp and antoher euWebApp. Your app logic should handle the case where users have access to both regions.  Or are you doing this because you are running your app in two different location?

Comment: Assume that those apps are not mine. they are maintained by other team for instance. All I maintain is the dashboard app. I save session to redis and send a cookie with redis id to respective apps and they should validate if this session is valid. However the question is should I store in two places since the apps that I might serve(EUWebApp or USWebApp in this case) maybe region based.

Comment: Then its not so easy to give a good answer. Need to know how these apps are handling the aurhentication, how this is stored in cookies and how its encrypted.

Comment: I am still not sure why those things matter for this answer. I could be using any tech stack or any authentication mechanism. But once authentication happens they land on my page. Thats when the question's premise starts. The details of transforming cookie to redis id or building security context in my app from redis is completely optional to whatever tech stack of language I choose. However those are details that should not be needed to answer this question. At least thats what I believe.

Comment: If you Just want to store the session in two places you should only do that in the cases where the user should have access to both sites. If not, save it only to the site where the user have access to. Once you receive the answer from the idp and you verify it and get the roles the user is member of, it might be better to Just redirect the user directly to the site they belong to based on the role they are member of. If they are member of both sites, redirect them to a Page where they can choose which site to go to. You can also pass the saml response when the user click on button 1 or 2.

Comment: The thing is I dont want to pass saml response coz integrating with saml is a pain and I dont want the apps that I serve to do that. Hence I am passing a token which they can check with redis. Anyway thanks and right now I am doing exactly what you said, I just wasnt sure if it was right to do so.